# Hi friends, is there any formula or script to highlight only duplicate words in google sheets from different column and in different rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

Friends Actually I am having some data in which some employees names are there along with time, where I want if only names are appearing two times in a given range then it should highlight with any color. Below is the data for better understanding I have highlighted two duplicate names with red.  Any help is highly appreciated.
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxwnE.png)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z3qK65eW4fjCfZrsA_zEIh8HhueLk1Sgp32E1Cf-u3g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Pls share a spreadsheet. People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Do you know all the employees names? So that we can take all the list of employees in a separate Gsheet and considering each employee name as substring we can check number of occurrences in given Gsheet.

Comment: In your screenshot, we can't even see a range, and we don't know what the full range of your data might be. I agree with Mike: "Pls share a spreadsheet..." and "make it easy for people to help you."

Comment: Hi friends, Thanks a lot for your reply. I am sharing you the spread sheet.

Comment: Please find below link for Gsheet                                                                                                              https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z3qK65eW4fjCfZrsA_zEIh8HhueLk1Sgp32E1Cf-u3g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a conditional formatting rule with formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A$3:$G$7,"*"&REGEXEXTRACT(A3,"^.+ (.+)$"))>1
```

`$A$3:$G$7` is the range of the timetable (dollar signs required), where `A3` is the top left cell (NO dollar signs)

Comment: Thank you very much, its highly appreciated @idfurw

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: once again thank you for your help. Can you please tell me if I want to check duplicate values in a single cell. Words or names are seperated with comma like this in a single cell of the google sheets as :-Monty, Rony, Andy, Rachel, Rony, Sandy, Andy         here you can see Rony and Andy are two times.  So how can I find or highlight that if it is in a single cell of google sheet.

Comment: Assuming the values are in `A1:A`, `=COUNTIF(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,", ",FALSE)),"select count(Col1) group by Col1"),">1")>0`

Comment: you are amazing, it worked fine. Thank you very much.  Can it be more enhanced; like what if I want to highlight only those names or words only ? If that I will get then it will be more awsome. Thanks in advance.  Really It was greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a script for that.